# economic growth or growth of economy

Tags: grammar

I wonder if you could tell me what is the difference between these two phrases?

> - economic growth
> - the growth of economy

I think the latter one is noun?

What about the the first phrase?

Answer (score -1):

Both of those are nouns, and they are essentially synonymous. Though you would usually need a determiner before *economy* on the second one.